# conditional logic for time of day in sql server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got a query that is pulling back data based on time of day.

In the database, I have each "Channel" with a StartTime and and EndTime, done in military as a varchar. So, 12:00am = 0000, 3:00am = 0300, 4:00pm = 1600, 10:00pm = 2200, etc.

The query I have pasted below works so long as the StartTime is "before" the EndTime, as its using some basic less than greater than comparisons. So if a channel has a starttime of 3am and an endtime of 4pm, and I pass in 5am, 0300 < 0500 < 1600, so it displays. Where I'm running into logic issue is the night ones, which sort of "overflow" into the next day. So, if a channel is from 11pm to 4am, 2300 > 0400, so it wont show if I pass in a time of say midnight, or 0000.

I just need some help in tweaking the logic to deal with that type of rollover scenario. The below scenario assumes that the time that I'm passing in is 12:30am. Let's say I have one channel in the database set for a StartTime of 10:00pm (2200), and an endtime of 4:00am (0400).

```
declare @TimeOfDay varchar(200)

set @TimeOfDay = '0030'

            select 
            ChannelID, c.ChannelName
            from Channels
            where 
            CONVERT(INT,FeaturedStartTime) < CONVERT(INT,@TimeOfDay)
            and CONVERT(INT,FeaturedEndTime) >  CONVERT(INT,@TimeOfDay)
```

Comment: Have you considered using `DATETIME` variables instead of `VARCHAR`?

Comment: Not really, I'm not a very talented sql programmer (as you may have ascertained), so the above was my big hammer approach, sans elegance. How would my query be modified to use this?

Comment: Don't be too hard on yourself.  We're all on a journey.

Comment: DateTime variables might not be appropriate, because they require a Date as well as a Time. You could perhaps make them serve your purpose by setting all of them to use the same Date (Jan 1st 1970?). But doing this doesn't impact the core of the OP's problem - he will still have to do something special to handle the tricky cases described in the question.

Comment: @JonathanHartley - I suppose it depends on the data types of the `FeaturedStartTime` and `FeaturedEndTime` columns.   Direct comparison of two `DATETIME` variables  from different sides of a midnight will certainly yield the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your condition to something like

```
WHERE 
    (CONVERT(INT,FeaturedStartTime) < CONVERT(INT,@TimeOfDay)
    AND CONVERT(INT,FeaturedEndTime) >  CONVERT(INT,@TimeOfDay)
    )
    OR
    (CONVERT(INT,FeaturedStartTime) > CONVERT(INT,FeaturedEndTime)
        AND (CONVERT(INT,@TimeOfDay) > CONVERT(INT,FeaturedStartTime)
             OR CONVERT(INT,@TimeOfDay) < CONVERT(INT,FeaturedEndTime)
        )
    )
```

We're basically adding another case in which the `StartTime` is greater than the `EndTime` but then the `searched time` needs to be *outside* this interval (i.e. either greater than `StartTime` or smaller than `EndTime`).

NB: Mind the parentheses!

Comment: I would point out that converting to an `int` is not necessary.

Comment: Probably... I'm more interested to convey the thinking behind :)

Comment: This actually worked perfectly. It may not be the best way to "do" this whole scenario, but it definitely fixed my scenario. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Having only hours to compare, you will only be able to get reliable results if there is a certainty that no channel will last **24 hours** or more.

For example the row with the entry: {1600 of one day and 1800 of a second day} will not be included in results if the @TimeOfDay = '0500' although it should be. So assuming you have fields like FeaturedStart**Date** and FeaturedEnd**Date** as well (e.g. '20160916') then:

If you need **inclusive** results (@TimeOfDay = 1600 or 2030 still hit the period 1600-2030) then:

```
WHERE
    (
      FeaturedEndTime >= @TimeOfDay
      AND
      FeaturedStartTime <= @TimeOfDay
    )
    OR
    ( 
      FeaturedStartTime > FeaturedEndTime
      AND
      (
        FeaturedEndTime >= @TimeOfDay
        OR
        FeaturedStartTime <= @TimeOfDay
      )
    )
    OR
    ( 
      FeaturedStartTime <= FeaturedEndTime
      AND
      FeaturedStartDate < FeaturedEndDate
    )
```

If you need **noninclusive** results then:

```
WHERE 
    (
      FeaturedEndTime > @TimeOfDay
      AND
      FeaturedStartTime < @TimeOfDay
    )
    OR
    ( 
      FeaturedStartTime > FeaturedEndTime
      AND
      (
        FeaturedEndTime > @TimeOfDay
        OR
        FeaturedStartTime < @TimeOfDay
      )
    )
    OR
    ( 
      FeaturedStartDate < FeaturedEndDate
      AND
      (
        FeaturedStartTime < FeaturedEndTime
        OR 
        (/*for consequence in being noninclusive*/
          FeaturedStartTime = FeaturedEndTime
          AND
          FeaturedStartTime <> @TimeOfDay
        )
    )
```

Keep in mind that if you'll use the **noninclusive** approach then none of your queries will return channels that started and ended in the same minute, for example @TimeOfDay = 1302 will not hit the period 1302-1302 (e.g. channel started at exactly 13:02:00 ended 13:02:59)